# Convert JavaScript number to a string with fixed length

Tags: javascript, string, formatting, string-formatting, number-formatting

I'm using Node.js to print numbers to the console and want them to be easy to read. Because the numbers are displayed in columns, they should be the same length. Is there any easy way to do this before I start writing a monster function?

I've tried `.toFixed()` and `.padStart()` but they don't work well in all situations.

Part of the problem is converting a number to a string with `.toString()` in JavaScript formats it with 'e' notation if the number is significantly small or large. I don't know how to prevent this. I went on the [ECMAScript website to view the implementation for `Number.prototype.toString()`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) and it's complicated.

Here are some examples of what I want:

```
Length: 8

Input                Desired Output
12345678          => 12345678
1234              => 1234.000 // Works with .toFixed()
0                 => 0.000000 // ^^
1234567890.0123   => 1.2345e9 // Doesn't work with .toFixed() or padStart()       
0.00000000012345  => 1.234e-9 // ^^
1234567890123.123 => 1.234e12 // ^^
-123.4            => -123.400 // Works with .toFixed()
0.0123456789      => 0.012345 // Works with .slice()
```

Comment: if you convert to int you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round . hope it helps

Comment: If you _don’t_ want the `e` notation, then how exactly do you want `1234567890.0123` displayed in _eight_ digits/characters …?

Comment: I'm fine with the e notation for the output. It's just if I call `Number(12334567890.0123).toString()`, I'll get something like `1.234567e9` from JavaScript - which is 10 characters long. I could remove 2 digits before the e but there's a few edge cases.